# How to compare numbers on consecutive lines in file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
15064 3:30
15401 
15716 
16152 
290 
881 
2048 4:00
2920
```

I want check the first value of each line, comparing it with the value of the previous line, and if it is less, print the value of number on the previous line. So the output should be:

```
16152
```

Is there a way I can do this with awk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes:

```
awk '$1 < prev { print prev } { prev = $1 }'
```

This prints `prev` for every line where the first field is less than the value stored in `prev` (which is 0 initially), and stores the first field in `prev` in all cases.